# hide message only during the set time

Tags: php, time

I am trying to hide a message between 2 particular timings and rest of the timings it should display.

the timings are

1. 07:30am to 10:30am

   and
2. 18:30pm to 00:00am midnight

currently i did the following code which works ok for 07:30am to 10:30am it does the job but now how do i combine the 18:30pm to 00:00am midnight??? please someone help me out with some good logic.

```
<?php
          date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
          $now = new DateTime();
          $fromTime = new DateTime();
          $fromTime->setTime(07,30);
          $toTime = new DateTime();
          $toTime->setTime(10,30);
          
          $fromTime1 = new DateTime();
          $fromTime1->setTime(18,30);
          $toTime1 = new DateTime();
          $toTime1->setTime(00,00);
          
          if ( $now < $fromTime || $now > $toTime) {
          ?>          

         This is a test message

         <?php
         }
         ?>
```

I tried doing like this

```
$now < $fromTime || $now > $toTime && $now < $fromTime1 || $now > $toTime1
```

but it messes up and displays the message even during 07:30am.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

It's prety simple, to check few dates interval, but, don't make mistakes with PHP logical operators (https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) :

```php
if ( ($now >= $fromTime && $now <= $toTime)   // If it's on the first interval
     ||                                       // Or
     ($now >= $fromTime1 && $now <= $toTime1) // If it's on the second one
) {
    echo 'Appear on the interval';            // I display the message.
}
```

Also, you've a mistake with your last variable `$toTime1`, you must to check from 18::00 to 00:00 ... Not from the current day ! (but 00:00 to the **next** day).

You can edit your code like this, by addind +1 day to your last variable :

```php
    $toTime1 = new DateTime();
    $toTime1->modify('+1 day');
    $toTime1->setTime(00,00);
```

Like this, your timings are good ;)

Don't forget this code (php) is managed by the server side. So, if your user don't reload the page, your message will be visible during your intervals. Maybe you can use JavaScript for hide the message during your intervals on the client side, in the case that the user remains on the page ;)

Hope I help you.